# Taking snapshot of SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a set of referential tables with different schema which we use as a reference data during integration of files. The reference data can be modified from the GUI.

And the requirement is, I need to create a snapshot of data if there are any changes. For eg., Users should be able to see which referential data has been used for particular date.

Option 1: Historize all the tables over night everyday with date. This way when users want to see the data used for particular date, we can easily query the corresponding history table. As users doesnt change the data everyday, this way we will make the database bigger day by day.

Option 2: Historize only the data(rows) which has been modified with modified date and use the view to fetch the data for particular days. But this way I need to write many views as the schema is different for different tables.

If you know of the best way I can use, I would appreciate it if you share your knowledge.

Thanks,

Comment: In SQL 2016 you have temporal tables. In SQL 2014, you'd need to create logic in triggers etc. which sounds like it might be prohibitive effort. Of course another option is to save the reference data along with the file integration info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if possible but:
**Option 3**: Create/Edit triggers OnInsert/Update/Delete to write new values to an "historical table" and include a timestamp.
To get the Admin data used on day "X" just use the timestamp.
Another option (again not sure if possible) is to add "start_dt/end_dt" to the admin tables and have the processes lookup only the active data
Sérgio

Comment: In this option, I need to make different keys for different tables to match on which data has been modified which is cumbersome when retrieving the results.

Comment: Ok, maybe i don't understand fully your issue. You want to know which data has been changed from previous record?

Comment: Also, not sure if it is possible in your env, but ideally you would have tables XX (master) and tables XX_HIST (wich would be a copy of the DDL of XX plus timestamp and any other comment fields for example.. for visualization purposes).

Gathering all admin data changes into a single table would be a bit complicated because they have different DDL's. Possible, but probably not worth the effort.